# Node specific settings in a puppet environment

Tags: puppet

I'm in the process of learning puppet and I'm running into what I assume is a pretty basic issue. For the purposes of keeping things simple, I'm using a puppet forge module rather than anything custom written. Here's what I'm using version wise:

puppet server: 5.1.3
puppet agent: 5.3.2
puppetlabs-java: 2.1.0

When I install the puppetlabs-java module, I am using `--modulepath /etc/puppetlabs/code/modules/`.

I currently have my agent configured to point at my puppet server and an environment I have named `example`.

The environment currently looks like this:

```
├── environment.conf
├── hiera.yaml
├── manifests
│   └── init.pp
└── modules
    └── java.pp
```

I have done nothing to `environment.conf` and `hiera.yaml`, they are currently defaults. My `init.pp` contains:

```
node 'node1' {
}

node 'node2' {
}
```

and my java.pp contains:

```
class { 'java':
  distribution => 'jre',
}
```

My issue is two fold. One if I place the java.pp in the manifest folder it applies java to both nodes, regardless of if I have called out an `include java` in either node. If I put the `include java` on either node, that works correctly and one node will get java and the other will not, but it does not appear to be respecting any of the settings I have in the `java.pp`. How can I accomplish only installing java to `node1` with my custom settings in the `java.pp` file?

Comment: This is kind of a broad question, but for starters to help you narrow down your question's focus, rename your `init.pp` to `site.pp` and do not place any other manifests in that directory. Next read about dir envs: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/environments_about.html. Then read about modules/classes: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/modules_fundamentals.html. That will help you fix your organization and code problems and get moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I place the java.pp in the manifest folder it applies java to both nodes, regardless of if I have called out an `include java` in either node.

Yes.  The catalog builder processes every manifest file in the environment's `manifests` directory for every node.  Your `java.pp` file contains a top-scope declaration of class `java`, so if that file is processed by the catalog builder then it will include class 'java' in the target node's manifest.

> If I put the `include java` on either node, that works correctly and one node will get java and the other will not, but it does not appear to be respecting any of the settings I have in the java.pp.

No, it wouldn't.  `include java` (or `class { 'java': ... }`) *declares* class `java`, thereby instructing the catalog builder to include that class in the target node's catalog.  The two forms are more or less alternatives, and both will cause the catalog builder to look for the a definition of class `java` in the environment's module path.  Your `java.pp` hasn't either the right name or the right location to be found in that search, which is good because it does not in fact contain the wanted definition.

To customize class parameters, you should start right away with [external data](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/hiera_intro.html) and [automatic data binding](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/hiera_automatic.html).  This is not the *only* way to bind values to class parameters, but it's the mechanism you should prefer, especially for declaring classes across module boundaries.

---

Regarding Hiera details, a very basic Hiera config for this purpose might consist of these parts:

**example/hiera.yaml**

```
# example/hiera.yaml
---
version: 5

defaults:
  datadir: data
  data_hash: yaml_data

hierarchy:
  - name: "Common data"
    path: "common.yaml"
```

**example/data/common.yaml**

```
---
java::distribution: jre
```

The "example" in those file names would be the main directory of your environment of the same name.  Note, by the way, that although you *can* add a new hierarchy level for every module, that would be unusual.  It's more typical to use hierarchies that map to an hierarchical categorization of the machines being configured; naming in the above anticipates such an arrangement, in which as yet there is only one category.

After having updated the module data, you might find that you need to make the master expire its environment cache.  One way to do that would be to restart the service.

Comment: To simplify part of the `include java` explanation for a beginner level (directed at asker), the `include` is pulling in the `puppetlabs-java` you installed and ignoring your `java.pp` because it is not in the right location.

Comment: Thanks John and Matt, these things make a lot of sense. I'm still struggling a bit with syntax though,

I've add a data directory to my environment and created a `java.yaml` which contains:
```---  
java:distribution:  
  - jre  ```

I've tried adding the name and path in the `hiera.yaml` but it doesn't seem to be picking up the data at all? Am I making a simple syntax error or am I misunderstanding what you were saying?

Comment: It's hard to tell with the way your YAML is squashed in the comment, but it looks like your data file has at least two problems: (1), the key you want is `java::distribution` (*two* colons between class name and parameter name); (2) presumably you want the value to be a string, not an array, so lose the '-' between key and value.

Comment: I typo'd on here, but my data file had the double colons, I changed it to a one liner that looks like `java::distribution: jre` and it still doesn't seem to be applying. I have a path in hiera.yaml under hiearchy that has the path set to  `path: java.yaml` though I would think from the `datadir` being set as default it would pick it up regardless?

Comment: @Merakel, I've added some information about Hiera configuration to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! Part of my issue it seems is the java module isn't doing what I asked for even under this format, so I tried with another simple module and it worked. I can troubleshoot the java issue on my own now that I know the correct formatting :)