# Puppet Include vs Class and Best Practices

Tags: puppet

When should I be using an include vs a class declaration? I am exploring creating a profile module right now, but am struggling with methodology and how I should lay things out.

A little background, I'm using the puppet-labs java module which can be found [here](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/java).

My ./modules/profile/manifests/init.pp looks like this:

```
class profile {

  ## Hiera Lookups
  $java_version = hiera('profile::jdk::package')

  class {'java':
    package => $java_version,
  }
}
```

This works fine, but I know that I can also remove the `class {'java':` block of the code and instead use `include java`. My question relates around two things. One, if I wanted to use an include statement for whatever reason, how could I still pass the package version from hiera to it? Second, is there a preferred method of doing this? Is the include something I really shouldn't be using, or are there advantages and disadvantages to each method?

My long term goal will be building out profile like modules for my environment. Likely I would have a default profile that applies to all of my servers, and then profiles for different application load outs. I could include the profiles into a role and apply things to my individual nodes at that level. Does this make sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When should I be using an include vs a class declaration?

Where a class declares another, internal-only class that belongs to the same module, you can consider using a resource-like class declaration.  That leverages your knowledge of the implementation details of the module, as you need to be able to prove that no other declaration of the class in question will be evaluated before the resource-like one.  If ever that constraint is violated, catalog building will fail.

Under all other circumstances, you should use `include` or one of its siblings, `require` and `contain`.

> One, if I wanted to use an include statement for whatever reason, how
>   could I still pass the package version from hiera to it?

Exactly the same way you would specify any other class parameter via Hiera.  [I already answered that for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46691593/node-specific-settings-in-a-puppet-environment).

> Second, is
>   there a preferred method of doing this?

Yes, see above.

> Is the include something I
>   really shouldn't be using, or are there advantages and disadvantages
>   to each method?

The `include` is what you *should* be using.  This is your default, with `require` and `contain` as alternatives for certain situations.  The resource-like declaration syntax seemed good to the Puppet team when they first introduced it, in Puppet 2.6, along with parameterized classes themselves.  But it turns out that that syntax introduced deep design problems into the language, and it has been a source of numerous bugs and headaches.  Automatic data binding was introduced in Puppet 3 in part to address many of those, allowing you to assign values to class parameters without using resource-like declarations.

The resource-like syntax has the single advantage -- if you want to consider it one -- that the parameter values are expressed directly in the manifest.  Conventional Puppet wisdom holds that it is better to separate data from code, however, so as to avoid needing to modify manifests as configuration requirements change.  Thus, expressing parameter values directly in the manifest is a good idea only if you are confident that they will never change.  The most significant category of such cases is when a class has read data from an external source (*i.e.* looked it up via Hiera), and wants to pass those values on to another class.

The resource-like syntax has the great disadvantage that if a resource-like declaration of a given class is evaluated anywhere during the construction of a catalog for a given target node, then it must be the first declaration of that class that is evaluated.  In contrast, any number of include-like declarations of the same class can be evaluated, whether instead of or in addition to a resource-like declaration.

Classes are singletons, so multiple declarations have no more effect on the target node than a single declaration.  Allowing them is extremely convenient.  Evaluation order of Puppet manifests is notoriously hard to predict, however, so if there is a resource-like declaration of a given class somewhere in the manifest set, it is very difficult in the general case to ensure that it is the first declaration of that class that is evaluated. That difficulty can be managed in the special case I described above.  This falls into the more general category of evaluation-order dependencies, and you should take care to ensure that your manifest set is free of those.

There are other issues with the resource-like syntax, but none as significant as the evaluation-order dependency.

---

#### Clarification with respect to automated data binding

Automated data binding, mentioned above, associates keys identifying class parameters with corresponding values for those parameters.  Compound values are supported if the back end supports them, which the default YAML back end in fact does.  Your comments on this answer suggest that you do not yet fully appreciate these details, and in particular that you do not recognize the significance of keys identifying (whole) class parameters.

I take your example of a class that could on one hand be declared via this resource-like declaration:

```
class { 'elasticsearch':
  config => { 'cluster.name' => 'clustername', 'node.name' => 'nodename' }
}
```

To use an include-like declaration instead, we must provide a value for the class's "config" parameter in the Hiera data.  The key for this value will be `elasticsearch::config` (<fully-qualified classname> :: <parameter name>).  The associated value is wanted puppet-side as a hash (a.k.a. "associative array", a.k.a. "map"), so that's how it is specified in the YAML-format Hiera data:

```
elasticsearch::config:
    "cluster.name": "clustername"
    "node.name":    "nodename"
```

<s>The hash nature of the value would be clearer if there were more than one entry.</s> If you're unfamiliar with YAML, then it would probably be worth your while to at least skim a primer, such as [the one at yaml.org](http://yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html).

With that data in place, we can now declare the class in our Puppet manifests simply via

```
include 'elasticsearch'
```

Comment: I think my issue is I am struggling with syntax for nested objects which I still can't seem to get working. The java example we used in the other question works fine, but for my actual use case it doesn't seem to follow the same rules. I'm using the elasticsearch module on puppetforge; the syntax for class declaration looks like this: `class { 'elasticsearch':  config => { 'cluster.name' => 'clustername' }}`. I've tried a bunch of different combinations but I can't seem to get it to take. I thought it would be something like: `elasticsearch::config::cluster.name: test-cluster`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations though, I realized the question was redundant after reading your comment.

Comment: @Merakel, I have added some commentary that I hope will help clear up some misunderstandings about formatting your Hiera data.

Comment: That's for the additional updates. I'm familiar with yaml syntax, I'm guess I'm  doing something else wrong because it doesn't seem to obey the rules that I'm used to seeing. Even following your updated directions I cannot get the configuration setting of "cluster.name" to take.

You commented that it would be easier to represent if there was more than one entry, another entry would be `node.name` if that makes it easier to show, regardless though following your instructions it still doesn't seem to take :/

Comment: @Merakel, I said that the hash nature of the data would be *clearer* in the YAML if there were more than one entry.  I have updated that to make it so.  But this has run far afield from the actual question.  If you want help with binding hash values to your class parameters via automatic data binding then please pose that as a separate question, and in that case please do be sure to provide a [mcve] in the question.